# How to correctly update packages?

Tags: packages

Newbie starting to work with packages. I can create and load a package. However, when I come to update my package, I find the procedure very laborious. This is what I'm currently doing;

- Update package in Mathematica front end and save.
- Delete the current version at $UserBaseDirectory/Applications. (If I
  omit this step, the old version will not be overwritten by the new
  version despite the steps below.)
- File/Install Package and point to updated source file.

  Needs["MyPackage`"]

Is there a simpler/more correct way of doing this as this seems very tedious, error-prone and frankly, incorrect? (The Update button in the front end doesn't seem to do anything other than update the list of functions)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using paclets? Here's a nice description of package/paclet development: https://mresources.github.io/tutorial/package-usage-and-development/basics/packages-in-mathematica.html

Comment: No, not using paclets at present. Thanks for the link though, taking a look now.

Comment: Are you developing a new package or are you trying to install a new version of someone else's package?

Comment: Jó napot Szabolcs. I'm developing a new package of my own.

Comment: Long time ago I wrote a package that allows one to cleanly unload or reload a package under development. It is named "PackageManipulations" and available [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html). It comes with a notebook with examples illustrating its functionality. I have not tested it with recent versions of Mathematica, but I guess it should just work. Check it out, it might work for you. Also,  you can simply add the location of your development version to `$Path` during development, and forget about `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`.

Comment: Leonid, thanks for the response. I updated the `$Path` variable so that it now includes the path to my package but my updated version is not recognized.
Thinking it might be a precedence thing, I deleted the old version at $UserBaseDirectory/Applications. This now elicits a failure message when I attempt to <<MyPackage`.
I really don't understand why such a brilliant piece of software like Mathematica has such an ugly and convoluted method for doing something so simple as updating packages.
Will check out `PackageManipulations`.

Comment: From Leonid's suggestion- it sounds like your `$Path` modification didn't point to your package directory (`FindFile` gives a quick test to confirm). The "standard" way to packages uses WolframWorkbench (WW) that handles all the path manipulations automatically in testing and then as part of its "build" ports the package to the *Applications* folder. Installing WW at this point may be overkill though and at any rate, many developers prefer their own workflow; also, I believe there is some native package support on the way. Perhaps in the interim ...

Comment: ...  one strategy might be to simply edit your .nb/.m/.wf file directly in the *Applications* folder. Alternatively,  altering `$Path` should be pretty straightforward and you could then write a  script to port/copy into the *Applications* folder when "building".

Comment: Thanks Ronald. I should have been more specific. Amending `$Path` works so long as I don't close the kernel session. If I close it and start a new session, the changes to $Path are lost. How does one permanently amend `$Path`?
Also, thanks for the WW suggestion. I am planning on using it going forward so perhaps I should take that route now.

Comment: Ah, I see I need to amend `init.m`. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Using *init.m* is perfectly workable and traditional. Of late though, I find the persistence framework more natural for such settings (I don't have to remember where the *init.m* file is and can modify more seamlessly from a kernel session). You might want to have a look at `Initialize`,`InitializationValue` and friends for this purpose.On WW, If familiar with similar IDE's, IMO, it can be quickly useful (and even occasionally otherwise) but coming in cold, there are also (more?) advantages to building workflows in the front-end by harnessing its unique features.

Comment: Thanks for that Ronald. The documentation is unclear on this. Does this mean if I use `Initialize` and `InitializationValue` that this will automatically update `init.m`? Or is it using some other mechanism? At any rate, this certainly seems the best way forward with the front end.

Comment: Instead of storing all your desired in initializations in `init.m` (including any adjustments to `$Path`) you can instead store them in `$Initialization`  (via the `InitializationValue` function). This setting (and subsequent start-up loading) is then persistent across kernel sessions.

Comment: Yes, thanks Ronald - that's what I'm already doing and it's working beautifully.